# Iterate two array lists and return with a lambda

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda

I have a method which has an ArrayList of Strings and an ArrayList of Characters. I want to iterate over each of the strings and see if they contain a character from the list of characters. If it does not I want to return that string. I'm having trouble putting this in a clean lambda expression (if at all possible). I looked at using Stream's filter but I don't know if it is possible to do with two ArrayLists and a return statement.

```
ArrayList<String> words = getWords();
ArrayList<Character> chars = getChars();
for (String word : words) {
   boolean doesNotContain = true;
   for (char letter : chars) {
      if (word.indexOf(letter) >= 0) {
         doesNotContain = false;
      }
   }
   if (doesNotContain) {
      return word;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your code sample returns the first word that is "sanitized" (contains none of the chars). Is this the intended behavior or do you actually want to get a sublist of sanitized words?

Comment: What do you return if no strings pass?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu yes. what i'm doing is correct. i want only the first word

Comment: @shmosel empty string

Comment: Btw, you can slightly improve performance by adding a `break;` after `doesNotContain = false;`. Or you can drop the variable and `continue outer;`.

Comment: Yeah, I had it in my code. Just forgot to put it here as I'm not on my main computer where the source is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
return words.stream()
        .filter(word -> chars.stream().noneMatch(letter -> word.indexOf(letter) >= 0))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse("");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method that checks whether a `String` contains any of the characters present in the list, e.g.:

```
private static boolean contains(String s, ArrayList<Character> chars) {
    return s.chars()
            .filter(c -> chars.contains((char) c))
            .findAny()
            .isPresent();
}
```

And call it from your code to filter out the `Strings` that do not contain any character, e.g.:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> filtered = words.stream()
    .filter(s -> !contains(s, chars))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you only want the first `String`, you can use `findFirst`, e.g.:

```
Optional<String> first = words.stream()
    .filter(s -> !contains(s, chars))
    .findFirst();

if(first.isPresent()){
    System.out.println(first.get());
}
```

Comment: What if I want only the first string. Should i just get the first position from the List or is there a better way to return only a string.

Comment: Don't treat an `Optional` like a nullable value: `first.ifPresent(System.out::println)`.